# Splice method used on a copy of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm a little bit confused about how spread operator works on an array of objects. Let's say I have an array of objects like:

```
const array = [
{ name: 'Object 1', body: '123'},
{ name: 'Object 2', body: '456'}];
```

and if I make a clone and use splice on the clone:

```
const cloneArray = [...array];
const newObject = { name: 'Object 3', body: '789'}
cloneArray.splice(1,1,newObject);
```

and I will have:

```
 const array = [
{ name: 'Object 1', body: '123'},
{ name: 'Object 2', body: '456'}];
 const cloneArray = [
{ name: 'Object 1', body: '123'},
{ name: 'Object 3', body: '789'}];
```

Only the cloned array is modified. The spread operator shouldn't make a shallow copy of the initial array, and force me to deep clone all the objects?
What am I missing here?

Comment: that's why developers use `spread` operator, to make a shallow copy

Comment: When shallow-copying objects (the default, be that with assignment, or like here, spreading an array of references), you are always just copying the reference. Here, if you do `cloneArray[0].name = 'coolNewValue';`, it will be reflected in `array` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not *modifying* the array entries.

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) *replaces* an array entry. Think of those objects as pointers to a piece of memory:

```
const array = [A, B];
const cloneArray = [...array];
//    ^ cloneArray = [A, B]

const newObject = C;
cloneArray.splice(1,1,newObject);
//    ^ cloneArray = [A, C]
```

Now, if you were to change the *contents* of `A`:

```
array[0].foo = 'Bar';
// Or
cloneArray[0].foo = 'Bar';
```

Then you'd see the change in both your source array, as well as in the clone.